# Hyper referencing in MathJax

Tags: support, status-bydesign, mathjax, hyperlinks

I've Googled and searched mathstackexchange, but cannot find out how to insert a blue URL reference in a question or answer. Can you give me an example that I can edit it to look at the Latex code?

Comment: Perhaps you meant *markdown* and not *MathJax*? The way to include links is explained in [editing help](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#links). One possibility is to use this: `[editing help](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#links)`. See also: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/845/how-to-include-a-link-in-the-text In the editor you also have button for inserting links and the keyboard shortcut Ctrl+L works, too.

Comment: @MartinSleziak's answer (it should be an answer) is the way to go. In $\LaTeX$, one needs to load `hyperref.sty` or similar to include hyperlinks.

Comment: @robjohn If this is indeed what the OP wanted to ask, then I think the question can be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @MartinSleziak: I searched for a previous instance of this question, but could not find one. Do you have one?

Comment: @robjohn I thought that the question I linked in my first comment could be a reasonable candidate.

Comment: @Martin: The link you provide is for having a link included via markdown. What robjohn is suggesting that the question is about including links via MathJax.

Comment: @MartinSleziak: Okay, if the OP intended markdown as you suggest, then yes, it is a duplicate of the question to which you link. If not, then there is no way to add a link within MathJax to my knowledge (and the question seems to be unique).

Comment: @robjohn: If I recall correctly, t.b. did that at least once.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: MathJax has the `\href` function that inserts hyperlinks. However, as I mention in a comment to AlexR's answer, the MathJax header on MathSE contains `Macros: { href: "{}" }`. Davide Cervone explains that `\href` is disabled since it is not considered safe. Perhaps t.b. did his magic before `\href` was disabled.

Comment: @robjohn: See Davide's answer. I think that this is what I remembered being done.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: oh, I remember doing that. I thought you were talking about a link to a URL.

Comment: I want to insert a hyperlink in MathSE and in chatroom using ctrl L     but it is not working

Answer (score 5):

@AlexR's suggestion can be implemented using `\label` and `\eqref` macros in order to get links from within an equation to another equation (but only such links).  E.g.

$$\sin^2(\theta) + \cos^2(\theta) = 1\tag{1}\label{dpvc-1}$$

and then a link in the text: \eqref{dpvc-1} is due to the Pythagorean theorem, and

$$\cos^2(\eta) + \sin^2(\eta)-1 \stackrel{\eqref{dpvc-1}}= 0$$

follows.

Note, however, that you do face the problem described in [this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11392/mathjax-preview-broken-when-equations-contain-labels) when using labels.  There is a work-around using the [SOUP script](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch).

Answer (score 1):

See [here](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/safe-mode.html) for a reference, however this does not seem to work on this site:
$$E \href{javascript:alert("Einstein says so!")}{=} mc^2$$
(C&P'ed the example from the MathJax page):
`$$E \href{javascript:alert("Einstein says so!")}{=} mc^2$$`

### Suggestion

If Links are really required, try this:

$$\sin^2(\theta) + \cos^2(\theta) = 1\tag{1}$$
[(1)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem) Is due to the pythagorean theorem
$$\cos^2(\eta) + \sin^2(\eta)-1 \stackrel{(1)}= 0$$

Comment: I tried `\href` because it is listed [here](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html#h), but, as you say, it is not enabled here.

Comment: @robjohn Is there anyone (SE employee?) who can officially confirm this?

Comment: I tried this example on a local page to which I have added a MathJax header. The example works on my local page, but I see `Macros: { href: "{}" }` in the MathJax header on the pages here, and that disables `\href`.

Comment: The `\href` macro is considered "unsafe" because it can allow answers to include javascript (like the alert in AlexR's message), and that means that posts could include evil code that a user could trigger inadvertently.  MathJax now includes a `safe` extension (see the [documentation](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/safe-mode.html) and [options](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/options/Safe.html#configure-safe) for details) that disables all such macros, but SE hasn't updated to use that.  Note that you can configure `\href` to allow `http://` references but not `javascript://` ones.

Comment: @Davide Imo this is a *major* flaw, about which I've been meaning to make a feature request. Often I want to post a long proof (e.g. in an \eqnarray) where each line links to prior answers to justify the inferences. To insert the links,  I have to break it into numerous MathJax lines, so losing the two-dimensional alignment afforded by the array. For me, this is one of the greatest pains currently in MathJax (besides the frequent Chrome crashes). Is there any workaround?

Comment: @BillDubuque You could use `\tag{1}` to set reference "labels" at the right:
$$a^2+b^2=c^2 \tag{1}$$
$$c \stackrel{(1)}= \sqrt{a^2+b^2}$$

Comment: It is not clear to me what "this" refers to when you say "this is a *major* flaw", the fact that SE has disabled `\href` (the subject of the comments above yours) or that you haven't been able to make a link from a line of an alignment (a new topic).  I suspect it is the latter, but in that case, you should be posting a new question, not asking a new one in comments.  Indeed, since `\href` is not enabled in SE, it would be better to do it on the [Mathjax forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/mathjax-users), since none of what you are discussing can be done here.

Comment: In any case, the answer to your question would require more than just a comment from me, but since it is not an answer to the original post, I am not able to use an answer, here.  If you post to the MathJax forum (or make a new question here in meta), I will respond there.  Note, however, that you can't use `\href` to make link from an entire line of an `\eqnarray` in $\rm\TeX$ either, so I'm not sure why you would expect to be able to in MathJax, and personally I don't consider this a flaw, let alone a major one.  There are some things you could do to get the effect I think you want, however.

Comment: @BillDubuque, forgot to tag you, so weren't sure you'd see the two comments above.

Comment: @Davide I am requesting the same functionality as the OP, i.e. the ability to embed a URL in MathJax code. Does that functionality currently exist? If not, can it be provided?

Comment: @Bill, yes, as pointed out by AlexR, MathJax supports the `\href` command (he links to the docs as well).  But StackExchange has disabled it, as indicated by robjohn.  That is not a flaw in MathJax, so your comment was confusing.  The inclusion of `\eqnarray` into the mix led me astray since I thought you were talking about not being able to use `\href` across the column breaks (which you can't, but that is also true in $\rm\LaTeX$).  The fact that you are breaking up the alignment in order to use Markdown links around the lines is not a flaw in MathJax either, so that was a confusion as well.

Comment: I pointed out that the `safe` extension allows a more fine-grained control over the URL's that can be included in `\href`, and that `javascript:` URL's can be excluded while `http:` and `https:` ones are allowed.  So yes, MathJax provides the functionality, but SE disables it, and yes, it *could* be provided safely if they chained the configuration.  But since all that was said before your comment, I was confused about what additional information you were after.

Comment: Davide Yes, I understand that. What I mean is that I consider it a major flaw in the *SE deployment* of MathJax that such url hyperlinks are not enabled. What possible rationale can there for disabling such am *essential* feature?  Obviously we desire to build *webs* of mathematical knowledge. Anything that hampers the ability to define links in those webs is a major impediment to constructing such knowledge bases. I am probably one of the heaviest linkers on MSE, so it particularly irks me. How can we get SE to enable this?

Comment: @Davide Btw, speaking of links, I heavily use color to "link" related objects in the same answer, which irks color-challenged readers. If there were functionality for *intra-document* linking that allowed user-configurable control over how the linked objects are highlighted (possibly only upon hover-over) then this might help address some of the problem for color-challenged readers. Is there any way currently to achieve such?

Comment: @Bill, Ok.  When you said "this is one of the greatest pains currently in MathJax", I thought you were complaining about MathJax, not SE.  As for why people disable things that we think are important, the current trend seems to be to disable anything that could potentially be misused (and `\href` could).  This is why Mathjax can't actually copy something directly to the clipboard, for example.  I suppose there is validity to that, but it is hard to take at times.  As for getting SE to change it, I guess the best way is to post a feature request to meta.

Comment: @Bill, As for highlighting linked items, I can't think of a way to do it that doesn't involve some javascript, and so you won't be able to do that here.  (You could if you were making your own pages, but not in a shared environment like this.)  I can see how to highlight *one* item as you hover over it, but not how to highlight the other associated item at the same time without access to javascript.

Comment: @Davide But enabling only the url capabilities of \href is completely safe, right? Thus I remain perplexed as to the rationale for disabling this crucial feature. The SE markdown language supports urls outside of MathJax, but not inside of it. I cannot make any sense of that design decision.

Comment: @Bill, If you mean allowing `http:` and `https:` URL's, then yes, I believe that to be safe.  But URL's in general include things like `javascript:` URL's, and those are not safe (they can allow any user to capture data about you and send it to their own site for collection, for example).  So that is why SE has disabled it.  The MathJax `safe` extension is new in v2.3, so is only recently available.  Note that SE only allows restricted URL's in their Markdown (no `javascript:`, and no relative links, for example).

Comment: To boil this down, I suggest a temporary solution if links are really required: Mark the equation using `\tag{A}` and then include a textual annotation below the math saying `[(A)](http://www.example.com)`

Comment: @Davide Yes, I know that. But, as I said, I request only linking to *web pages* (http[s]: or, possibly ftp: too), which is no less safe than the capability already offered for such in SE's markdown language (I didn't check if SE supports ftp:).

Comment: @AlexR Yes, that's what I sometimes do, but it's not a good solution because a reader may need to scroll down a few pages to find the link. Also, I want the links to be on existing entities (e.g. arrows $\Rightarrow$ or $\iff),\,$ not on some spurious object that plays no role in the text other than to hold a link.

Comment: @BillDubuque I haven't seen many so-long questions that this would be a burden to me (FullHD solution at least), so I suggest using `\stackrel{(ABC)}\Rightarrow` as a work-around for the time being.

Comment: @AlexR Yes, I do already use variants of that. But it would be much nicer to have *first-class links*, esp. when that feature is already implemented in MathJax, and requires an abolutely trivial configuration change to enable it on MSE. If you've ever read my posts, you'll notice that they heavily link to others posts and external sources.

Comment: @BillDubuque Agreed, I suggest you open a [meta-tag:feature-request] for that? I'll surely support it.

Comment: @Bill, the ability to separate safe from unsafe URL's did not exist in MathJax before several months ago, which is why SE had the entire macro disabled.  At this point, it is a matter of getting the SE developers' attention rather than a capabilities issue.  It was not clear from your message that you meant only `http:`, `https:` and `ftp:` links, since you said "urls", which includes all protocols.  You seemed confused by why SE would have disabled `\href`, which is why I tried to explain it (not defend it).

Comment: @Davide Sorry, I think there was a disconnect from the start. I always meant linking to web pages, not any extended URL/URI features. Why else would I be so surprised that it has not been enabled yet? So what do you recommend as the best way to get it enabled? Is that something best done by you contacting the appropriate SE folks, or through a general feature request, or perhaps some other way? It's good to know that you are already one step ahead of my feature requests!

Comment: @Bill, I can see what I can do, but I don't have any particular pull.  I think the best approach is a feature request here, since they do monitor those.

Comment: @Davide Well this question is such a feature request, so let's see how SE responds.

Comment: @Bill, actually not.  It is a support request, which is asking about how to use the current features of the site.  It has already been marked as "status-bydesign" (correctly), with no additional comment.  I suggest you make a question tagged as "feature-request" that asks for enabling of the MathJax safe extension.

Comment: @BillDubuque I've opened a feature-request over [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/12674/enable-safe-href-in-mathjax)